# Unable to execute a promise in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am completely new to node.js, All I want to do is to use the inquirer NPM to ask a few questions, get the answers to those questions plug into a template literals and create a readme.md file from it. for some reason, my code doesn't work. Could someone point out what have I done wrong here? I feel like I'm missing some parameter when creating the promise maybe??

````
const inquirer = require("inquirer")
const fs = require("fs")
const util = require("util")
const readme = () => {
return `
# ${data.title} 
License covered under ${data.license}
## Table of Contents

1. [Description](#description)
2. [Installation](#installation)
3. [Usage](#usage)
4. [License](#license)
5. [Contributing](#contributing)
6. [Test](#test)
7. [Question](#question)

## Description
${data.description}

## Installation 
${data.installation}
## Usage 
\```
${data.usage}
\```

## License 
${license}
## Contributing
Accepting contribution: ${data.contribution}
${data.contributionRequirement}

## Tests
${data.test}

## Questions 

- Github Repo : 
- Email : ${data.email} `
}


// array of questions for user
const questions = [
{
  type: "input",
  name: "title",
  message: "What is the title of your project",
  default: "Not Available"
},  
{
  type: "input",
  name: "username",
  message: "What is your Github username?",
  default: "Not Available"
},
{
  type: "input",
  name: "email",
  message: "What is your email address?",
  default: "Not Available"
},
{
  type: "input",
  name: "contact",
  message: "How do you want people to reach you?",
  default: "Not Available"
},
{
  type: "input",
  name: "description",
  message: "Please type a short description of your project ( When you are done, hit ESC & type \":wq\" to exit editor )",
  default: "Not Available"
},
{
  type: "input",
  name: "installation",
  message: "How do you install this application? ( When you are done, hit ESC type \":wq\" to exit editor) ",
  default: "Not Available"
},
{
  type: "input",
  name: "usage",
  message: "Give example of some ways you can use this application ( When you are done, hit ESC & type \":wq\" to exit editor)",
  default: "Not Available"
},
{ 
  type: "list",
  name: "license",
  message: "What kind of license would you like to use?",
  choices: ["MIT","Microsoft Public License","Mozilla Public License 2.0","Academic Free License v3.0","Open Software License 3.0","Creative Commons Attribution 4.0"],
  default: "Not Available"
},
{
  type: "confirm",
  name: "contribution",
  message: "Are you open to contribution?",
  default: "Not Available"
},
{
  type: "input",
  name: "contributionRequirement",
  message: "If Yes, What are your requirement for giving contribution?",
  default: "Not Available"
},
{
  type: "input",
  name: "test",
  message: "Please give instructions for testing of this project ( When you are done, hit ESC & type \":wq\" to exit editor)",
  default: "Not Available"
}
]

// function to write README file
function writeToFile(fileName, data) {
  fs.writeFile(fileName, data, "utf8", function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);}
  })}

// function to initialize program
const init = new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
  resolve(inquirer.prompt(questions))
})

// function call to initialize program
init.then(writeToFile("test.md",readme)
````

Comment: Where does `data` come from in your template literal?

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Rather than saying "it doesn't work", it's much better to describe what *is* happening vs what *should* happen.

Answer (score 1):

`readme` should run with result when `inquirer` get all input.

```js
const inquirer = require ('inquirer');
const fs = require ('fs');
const util = require ('util');

const readme = data => {
  return `
# ${data.title} 
License covered under ${data.license}
## Table of Contents

1. [Description](#description)
2. [Installation](#installation)
3. [Usage](#usage)
4. [License](#license)
5. [Contributing](#contributing)
6. [Test](#test)
7. [Question](#question)

## Description
${data.description}

## Installation 
${data.installation}
## Usage 
\`\`\`
${data.usage}
\`\`\`

## License 
${data.license}
## Contributing
Accepting contribution: ${data.contribution}
${data.contributionRequirement}

## Tests
${data.test}

## Questions 

- Github Repo : 
- Email : ${data.email} `;
};

// array of questions for user
const questions = [
  {
    type: 'input',
    name: 'title',
    message: 'What is the title of your project',
    default: 'Not Available',
  },
  {
    type: 'input',
    name: 'username',
    message: 'What is your Github username?',
    default: 'Not Available',
  },
  {
    type: 'input',
    name: 'email',
    message: 'What is your email address?',
    default: 'Not Available',
  },
  {
    type: 'input',
    name: 'contact',
    message: 'How do you want people to reach you?',
    default: 'Not Available',
  },
  {
    type: 'input',
    name: 'description',
    message: 'Please type a short description of your project ( When you are done, hit ESC & type ":wq" to exit editor )',
    default: 'Not Available',
  },
  {
    type: 'input',
    name: 'installation',
    message: 'How do you install this application? ( When you are done, hit ESC type ":wq" to exit editor) ',
    default: 'Not Available',
  },
  {
    type: 'input',
    name: 'usage',
    message: 'Give example of some ways you can use this application ( When you are done, hit ESC & type ":wq" to exit editor)',
    default: 'Not Available',
  },
  {
    type: 'list',
    name: 'license',
    message: 'What kind of license would you like to use?',
    choices: [
      'MIT',
      'Microsoft Public License',
      'Mozilla Public License 2.0',
      'Academic Free License v3.0',
      'Open Software License 3.0',
      'Creative Commons Attribution 4.0',
    ],
    default: 'Not Available',
  },
  {
    type: 'confirm',
    name: 'contribution',
    message: 'Are you open to contribution?',
    default: 'Not Available',
  },
  {
    type: 'input',
    name: 'contributionRequirement',
    message: 'If Yes, What are your requirement for giving contribution?',
    default: 'Not Available',
  },
  {
    type: 'input',
    name: 'test',
    message: 'Please give instructions for testing of this project ( When you are done, hit ESC & type ":wq" to exit editor)',
    default: 'Not Available',
  },
];

// function to write README file
function writeToFile (fileName, data) {
  fs.writeFile (fileName, data, 'utf8', function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log (err);
    }
  });
}

// function call to initialize program
inquirer.prompt(questions).then(answer => {
    writeToFile('test.md', readme(answer))
});
```